# Make a long HTML select for better usability

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, usability

In a HTML select, I've 10 optgroup and each optgroup has 30 items, so there are 300s option in a select...it is a huge list.

Is it possible to use some CSS or JS library so the options under each optgroup will be displayed only when current optgroup is selected?

Something like the 2 level JS menu but I am using a HTML select as the source. Is it possible?

Comment: Why not using two different `select` where the second one loads its items based on the first one? Or one select element is your only option?

Comment: could create a 2 level menu from the optgroups and options and hide the select. When an item selected from menu update select value. Likely a plugin already available to do this with

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible to populate a select box in that way.

The trick would be to know when a values are for the first level, and when they are just refill the select. Then onchange event should be doing something like:

```
function selChange(sel) {
    var optVal = sel.val();
    if (isFirstLevel(optVal)) {
        fill_options("#select", optVal)
    }
}
```

In case of an ajax call to the backend fill_options could be something like:

```
function fill_options(selectId, optVal) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://example.com/ajax_refill',
        data: {'category': optVal },
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data) {

           var select = $(selectId), options = '';
           select.empty();      

           for(var i=0;i<data.length; i++)
           {
            options += "<option value='"+data[i].id+"'>"+ data[i].name +"</option>";              
           }

           select.append(options);
        }
    });
}
```

The function isFirstLevel() ideally depends on the structure (syntax) of the values so a simple operation like a regex will do, but it can be arbitrarily complex, doing ajax calls and any other stuff needed.

But the user interface of such box may be confusing to the user, having two select boxes may be more intuitive solution for the users.

Comment: I don’t think there is anything in the question that suggests that interaction with a served is needed, or desired, or even possible (this could be a standalone app).

Comment: Yes you're right then changing the $.ajax() call for a generic function retrieving the new options, I'll try to do that.